# Cannot find module 'web3' meteor

Tags: web3js, meteor

I am trying to use the web3 API through my project in meteor. I saw an example that included web3 the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
...code... </script>
```

When i run the project i get this error "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'web3'". I've already added web3 to meteor withe this command: meteor add ethereum:web3 . What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is to do with the version of web3 you have installed. Try installing with this version :

```
npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3@0.20.1
```

Comment: Hello, it was not because of the version but web3 overall. I adding some other stuff (it was long time ago i dont remember what) that messed up the installation. after installing again web3 it worked

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this that worked for me. Assuming your modules are in node_modules in your project directory and you're working with a file that's a sibling to that directory:

```
var Web3 = require('./web3');
```

If the files further down the file hierarchy, I assume a full path will work here as well, where `./` refers to project root