# Web3 Empty Object Server Side in Meteor

Tags: web3js, meteor, connections, interoperability

Created new `--bare` Meteor project (release 1.8).

Used `meteor npm install --save web3` to add web3 to the project from `npmjs.org`.

In code `server.js` use:

```
Web3 = require('web3')
console.log(Web3) // returns '{}'
```

Nothing else added to Meteor project. Client side use is as expected.

Toolkit: MacOS, Ganache, Truffle, Web3 version 1

I did of course discover that this can be a consequence of [recursion in package dependencies](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10065)

Is this a known issue? Is it a bug? What would be the best direction to go in determining the root cause of this issue?

Related SO Questions/Threads:

[Meteor server side contract event watch error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37864/meteor-server-side-contract-event-watch-error)

[Problem with meteor server side call to Ethereum node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37956/problem-with-meteor-server-side-call-to-ethereum-node)

[Cannot find module 'web3' meteor](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/cannot-find-module-web3-meteor)

[How do you connect to a node from the server side of a meteor app](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16660/how-do-you-connect-to-a-node-from-the-server-side-of-a-meteor-app)

**Update:**

After seeing many unresolved questions/issues on this, I've bumped an [existing github](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1333) issue for tracking. Additionally there is a [Meteor Forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/problem-with-server-side-call-to-ethereum-node/41879/2) post, and I've created a post on the [Ethereum Forums](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/19020/getting-web3-to-work-with-meteor-server/p1?new=1)

Comment: Also tried using just the distributed library file `web3.js` from [github dist](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js) with similar results.

Comment: It's obviously better to use NPM for this, but it doesn't even work when you include the `dist` file and directly reference it?  Like, `require('./web3.dist.js');`?  The `./` ensures it does a direct file lookup before `node_modules`.

Comment: @ohsully yes the direct reference to the dist file is how I tested it. It works on just a node project, and from previous experience I have seen when package dependency recursion resulted in this effect for a different project and npm package I was working with. Therefore I assume there is some conflict with Meteor on the server side. It's interesting to note also that it is a new `--bare` project at the latest Meteor version.

Comment: Update: have installed both from npm and dist file in parallel, and can try to import/require either on server. Still a bare new empty meteor project, have only downloaded dist file and run `meteor npm install --save web3`. Same problem persists.

Comment: Update on solution progress: I have been able to get web3 functioning on both server and client in Meteor (1.7/1.8). This was accomplished by first removing `meteor-node-stubs` npm package. This had a dependency conflict with web3 (candidate package is `crypto-browserify`). After re-adding the `meteor-node-stubs` package after installing web3 in the project, the conflict seems to have been resolved. It seems that load order of dependencies may have been the problem. More testing needed to determine exactly the specific fix. Perhaps others can test this 'workaround' solution?

Comment: I'm not doing active Meteor development anymore, but if you've got it working, then it sounds like you should write that up and accept your own answer!  Props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further testing, there seems to be a consistent work around for getting the `require` of the Web3 package to work on the server in Meteor.

Tested procedure on both new and existing Meteor projects (version 1.7/1.8):

1. Create a new meteor project (optional) or navigate to the directory of an existing project.
2. In the Meteor project directory use `meteor npm uninstall --save meteor-node-stubs`.
3. Next do: `meteor npm install --save web3`
4. Now re-add `meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs`
5. Do the normal import and instantiate the web 3 object as per [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html)

The web3 instance should now be working as expected on the Meteor server which you can check after launching the app using `meteor shell`.

It seems there is an issue in the load order of conflicting dependency packages, with the candidate offending package being `crypto-browserify`.